# SQLite - Turning Integers into Currency

Tags: sql, sqlite

I recently asked a question about turning currency (eg $20,000) into integers, but how might I go about turning the integers back into currency?

E.g. 100000 -> 100,000. The dollar sign doesn't really matter to me, I'd just like a general idea about how to add commas where appropriate. I've read others use convert and cast

> E.g: convert(salary,cast(123456789 as money),1)

but either they don't work in SQLite or I've been placing them wrongly. If it's bad practice to do so then it's no big deal.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: You can use format() function as `format(salary,0)`

Answer (score 0):

This will work

`SELECT (round(salary), 0) || '$') AS field FROM your_table`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `PRINTF` function.

```
sqlite> SELECT PRINTF('%,d',12345678);
12,345,678
```

I don't think this works with `f` or `g` codes, though.

Works at least in SQLite 3.31.1.

Reference: [SQLite built-in printf](https://www.sqlite.org/printf.html)